# How to count concurrent instances of a running function using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so let's say I have index.php, which has numerous functions. Not all functions are executed equally, so I only want to log how many PHP instances are currently running which executed one specific function.

I thought of logging it either in a file or better, in a database. So at the start of the function execution, I would increment a database value by 1, at the end of the script, I would just decrement it. This way I could check how many parallel instances of that function are running in real time.

Now, the issue is that if a script fails execution because of an error, or perhaps timeout, there is no way to decrement the value and the value would just start rising without ever hitting 0.

So my question is, how can I solve this without introducing bugs like these which just destroy the whole purpose of what I need.

Thanks for all the ideas and help.

Comment: If you introduce logging at the start and end of every function, you will probably introduce a noticeable performance problem.

Comment: Read again. I don't want to log start of every function. I have one function that takes way too long to execute because it is loading external resources. I want to limit number of those simultaneous instances because it would kill the site. My hosting gives me 6 PHP instances which can run at the same time. If 6 people do an action which results in execution of this function, the site can be down for seconds before accepting more requests.

Comment: I apologize, your comment explains the situation better. I would honestly look into using locks or mutexes, probably at the file system level. You have a small finite number of things, so you could just try acquiring a lock on `instance-1`, through `6`. Symfony has a great locking component that also supports automatic expiration via TTL in the event of a crash. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html

Comment: I dont have access to the exec function. You see, it's hosted on a server that runs thousands of other websites. It's not a VPS.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you shouldn't need `exec` for locking, especially if you are using the file system as a lock. You are basically just creating a file called `/path/to/locks/instance-1.lock`, doing your work, then deleting that file. While that code is running, another process would notice that `1` is used so it would try `2`, and on to `6`.